# Sqlite database retreival of multiple data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

In sqLite,i have 3 values inserted in a table in my database ,from an activity.
I need to reteive those 3 values from the database,from another activity...The retreival of the first value from the table is possible..i cant retreive the remaining 2 values...How can the cursor object be defined to do the same???

```
        myDB = MyService.this.openOrCreateDatabase("antitheft", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cursor1 = myDB.query("SimSerial", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor1.moveToLast();
        String ss1 = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("simno"));
        cursor2.moveToFirst();
        String num1 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("secure"));
```

Comment: you have all values in one table or different tables?

Comment: values are in the same table....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the query for selecting all the records and then iterate through the records.

```
Cursor cursor1 = myDB.query("SimSerial", null, null, null, null, null, null);

cursor1.moveToFirst();
while(!cursor1.isAfterLast()){
   cursor1.getString(....);
   cursor1.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate cursor. For that you can use following example.

```
    Cursor cur = myDB.query("SimSerial", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
        String str = cur.getString(1);
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();
```